# alert location services disabled when click mylocation button

Tags: android, google-maps, mylocationoverlay

I've enabled My Location button with this code in my google map

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

When I click on My Location button

If the location services is disabled, related messages ("location services disabled") are not shown for me

I want this message to be shown if it is disabled, such as Google Maps software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can implement that yourself quite easily:

```
googleMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap
        .OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)
                getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "GPS not available!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true; // GPS not available, consume the click
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```